# Get color of an element within a motion tween using JSFL in Flash CS6

Tags: flash, jsfl

I'm writing a jsfl script to export animations in Flash CS6 to a format we desired. Here's the problem, as we used **motion tween** for animation, we can correctly get position, rotation and scale of the element using the following code. However the code cannot work with color information:

```js
var element = something;
for( var frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < layer.frames.length; frameIndex++ )
{
    timeline.currentFrame = frameIndex;
    fl.trace( element.x + ", " + element.y );             // Works
    fl.trace( element.scaleX + ", " + element.scaleY );   // Works
    fl.trace( element.rotation );                         // Works
    fl.trace( element.colorAlphaPercent );                // DOES NOT WORK
}
```

We did a simple animation that the element's alpha changes from 0 to 100, linear. As we print out all the `colorAlphaPercent` value from start to end, turns out that it's all 0. We tested more and discovered that no matter what animation you make, on any frame, the `colorAlphaPercent` value always equals the value on the first frame. The same thing happens on `colorAlphaAmount` and other color values (red, green, blue).

The only way we can get rid of this is to do the `Convert to frame by frame animation` on the motion tween. But that break up one element into many of them, so that I can't tell if they are originally the same element.

So... is there anyone know how to get the color information from an element within a motion tween? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I've ran into the same issue a while ago. I ended up writing my own algorithm that reads and interpolates the alpha values between the start and end frame of a motion tween. Here's my question & answer in case that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280834/how-can-i-get-the-alpha-value-on-an-instance-in-jsfl

Comment: Thanks @bigp, I ended up with parsing the xml from frame.getMotionObjectXML(), and interpolating it. It makes the script running really slow, but works. Thanks for your MathUtils class, I can use it somewhere else :D